# Is it possible to nest generics in a typescript type definition?

Tags: generics, typescript, functional-programming, polymorphism

I want to define a map function, that can generically transform any container. Whether that is an array, or a stream, or an observable, or any old monad etc.
I think in order to model this, I need some form of nested generics. So that I can define `<T<U>>`.

```
let f : (
    fn: (a:number) => string,
    list:number[]     
) => string[]

var toFixed = (a=0) => a.toFixed(2)
var list = [1,2,3]

f( toFixed , list ) //=> string[] ✓

// but what if I want to make the array's generic?
let f2 : <T,U>(
    fn: (a:T) => U,
    list:T[]     
) => U[]

// that's simple
f2(toFixed, list) //=> string[] ✓

// but how do you support generic *containers*?
// so that instead of an array, its an Observable, or
// any Monad or Functor?

let f3 : <T,U, V> (
    fn: (a:T) => U,
    container: V<T>
) => V<U> 

interface Observable <T> {}
interface Maybe <T> {}
interface Future<T> {}

let observable : Observable<number>
let maybe : Maybe<number>
let future : Future<number> 


f3(toFixed, observable) // => any ✖
// We want it to be: Observable<string>

f3(toFixed, maybe) // => any ✖
// We want it to be: Maybe<string>

f3(toFixed, future) // => any ✖
// We want it to be: Future<string>

f3(toFixed, [1,2,3]) // => any ✖
// We want it to be: string[]
```

If there is another way to model this behaviour, I'd like to hear any alternatives.

Comment: Unfortunately higher-kinded types are not supported in TypeScript (yet), see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly but you could create an intermediate type as so:

```
type Mappable<T> = {
    map: <U>(fn: (t: T) => U) => Mappable<U>;
};

type map = <A, B>(fn: (a: A) => B) => (m: Mappable<A>) => Mappable<B>;

const map: map = (fn) => (m) => m.map(fn);
```

You will lose some type information doing this (stream/array will both come out as mappables) but if there is a finite number of types you want to generically map over you might be able to overcome this with infered or union types that extend mappable.